# Android Canvas background

Tags: android, background-image, android-canvas

There are a lot of small images in background of my view. And position of each image depends on screen resolution. Also there are other objects that dynamically redraws after onToch ivent. It works fine without background but when i try to draw it in onDraw() i get KeyDispatchingTimedOut error. How can i compose a backgrount in a single bitmap when my app first starts, or there are other better solutions?

Comment: could you show us your onDraw() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
canvas.draw(yourSmallImage, posX, posY, null);
....
c.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
```

This will use 'background' as a scratchpad, then write the completed background image to the current canvas when you are done 'scratching' :-)